# Python: writing a text file with a lot of variables

Tags: python, csv, file-writing

I need to create (from Python code) a text file with in each line some 50 variables, separated by comm's. I take the canonical way to be
    output.write ("{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}, ... \n".format(v,v,v,v,...
But that will be hard to read and difficult to maintain with such a lot of variables. Any other suggestions? I have thought of using the csv module, after all what I am writing is (kind of) a csv file, but thought I'd hear around for other suggestions first.

Comment: Maybe have a look at [`numpy`'s IO](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.io.html). Or just [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) or [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)

Comment: If you have a function with 50 variables you should _seriously_ think about reorganizing that code. You should try to combine those variables into groups using lists, tuples, dictionaries, or custom classes. If those 50 items were all in a list or tuple called `things` you could print them to your file with `output.write(','.join([str(u) for u in things]) + '\n')`.

Answer (score 0):

### Using lists

When reaching a handful of variables that are related to each other, it is common to use a `list` or a `dict`. If you create a list:

```
myrow = []
myrow.append(v1)
...
```

This also allows for easier looping over each value. Once you have done that you can easily concatenate it to a string:

```
f.write(','.join(myrow))
```

In case your row might contain any commas (or whatever you use as a delimiter) you must ensure escaping. In this case a CSV modules helps:

```
import csv
with open('myfile.csv', 'w') as f:
  fw = csv.writer(f)
  fw.writerow(myrow)   # where myrow is a list
```

### Using dicts

Some people prefer to add additional structure, e.g.:

```
myrow = {}
myrow['speed'] = speed_value
myrow['some_other_row'] = other_value

import csv
with open('myfile.csv', 'w') as f:
  fw = csv.writer(f)
  fw.writerow(myrow)
```

Comment: I did not know a dict can be written out as a whole, that looks promising.

Comment: @KarelAdams I mean to write a dict per row. You would probably have a list of dictionaries to represent all rows.

Answer (score 0):

If you can sort of your variables, you could use locals().

for example:

I set three variables:

```
var1 = 'xx'
var2 = 'yy'
var3 = 'zz'
```

and I can sort of them by sorted().

```
def sort(x):
    if len(x) != 4:
        return '99'
    else:
        return x[-1]

sortVars = sorted(locals(), key=sort)
```

Then, using **`for`** combination them.

```
result = ''

for i in sortVars[:3]:
    result += locals()[i]

print(result)
```